# UINavigationItem titleView with dynamic width

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, titleview

I am using the `titleView` property of a `UINavigationBar` inside a `UINavigationController`. Is there any way to have the `titleView`'s width be dynamically adjusted to fill the space in between the any buttons on the left and any buttons on the right? (Ideally without manual calculations)

Comment: Why don't you use the `UIViewController`'s `title` property ? In this way the title will be resized and will fill all the space available.

Comment: I have a custom view with 2 UILabels and 2 images

Comment: The thing is that iOS will create by default some space between the bar buttons and the title view, and since you can't get the width of the bar buttons, I don't think there is an easy solution for this.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Any other solutions you might recommend?

Comment: Well I had this issue to but I didn't had enough time to search for a clean solution so I used brute force and try and error to find the max with that the titleView can have.

Comment: Well if you can't get the width of bar buttons, how exactly did you determine this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35304/discussion-between-roozbubu-and-danypata)

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have the source code for the project anymore.